Trouble Installing fswatch for Dart Project on Windows
I'm currently working on a Dart project on Windows and I'm trying to integrate fswatch for file system monitoring. However, I'm encountering some difficulties with the installation process as there seems to be a lack of clear documentation specifically for Windows users, especially for beginners like myself.
Could someone please provide clear, step-by-step instructions on how to properly install fswatch for a Dart project on Windows? Additionally, any tips or insights on potential pitfalls to watch out for during the installation process would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
I've attempted to install fswatch using various methods, including using package managers as well as trying manual installations from source. However, none of these methods have been successful so far.

Refer fswatch Documentation :

Download Cygwin with following components :
Cygwin is a required dependency and must be installed to provide the
toolchain and the libraries required by fswatch.  The current Cygwin
distribution can be downloaded at:
https://cygwin.com

Cygwin is a modular environment and the following componentes are
required to successfully build fswatch:

GNU GCC C++ compiler.

GNU Autoconf.

GNU Automake.

GNU Autoconf.

GNU libtool.

GNU gettext


Follow these steps

Download the zip file from https://emcrisostomo.github.io/fswatch/

Extract this zip file

Open Cygwin and move to the Directory folder
Example :
cd /cygdrive/c/folder

Run the Build Commands:

After navigating to the correct directory and ensuring you have all
necessary tools, run the build commands:
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install



Hope this works!
